# Setting up a conservation of energy problem

Tags: proof-verification, classical-mechanics

> A smooth wire is shaped into a circle of centre O and radius 0.8m. The wire is fixed in a vertical plane.
>   A small bead P of mass 0.03 kg is threaded on the wire and is projected along the wire from the highest point with a speed of $4.2$ ms$^{-1}$. When OP makes an angle $\theta$ with the upward vertical the speed of P is
>   $v$ ms$^{-1}$. Show that $v^2=33.32-15.68cos\theta $

When forming the conservation of energy equation for when the line OP makes an angle $\theta$, in addition to the equation for kinetic energy I wrote that GPE = $mgr(1-cos \theta)$, but doing this got me $+15.68$ instead of $-15.68$. The mark scheme says use $-mgr(1-cos\theta)$, but I don't understand why - I thought $mgr(1-cos\theta)$ works regardless of the position of the particle in the circular motion? Why does it need to be negative?

Comment: The final kinetic energy is the sum of the initial kinetic energy plus the loss in gravitational potential energy (because that gets converted into kinetic energy). Now, the bead loses a height of $r(1 - \cos \theta)$, hence the loss in GPE is $mgr(1 - \cos \theta)$ and hence the conservation of energy can be written as $0.5 mv^2 = 0.5 mu^2 + mgr(1 - \cos \theta)$. This gives us the required result.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the energy is the sum of kinetic and potential energy, and that this total energy should stay constant.
$$
E=\frac{mv(t)^2}2+mgr(1-\cosθ(t)).
$$
What is asked is a formula where $v(t)$ is computed from $v(0)$ and $θ(t)$. Additionally, we know that $θ(0)=0$. When solving 
$$
\frac{mv(0)^2}2=E=\frac{mv(t)^2}2+mgr(1-\cosθ(t)).
$$
for the kinetic energy at time $t$, the potential term is subtracted from both sides.